# refreshonly not working with Puppet exec resource

Tags: puppet, user-management, rhel6

I am using the following user resource to create a `unix` user and then set an initial password for the user. I then performed an exec with chage command to force the user to change his password after his first login.The manifest is as follows

```
node 'node2.example.com','node3.example.com'{
  user {
     'askar':
      ensure  => 'present',
      managehome => 'true',
      comment => 'Laskar Home',
      home    => '/home/askar',
      shell   => '/bin/bash',
      expiry  => '2016-04-22',
      password => '$1$T7iMiuVY$bVjrtyWV4diXBKlCgcDKT0',
      password_min_age => '20',
      password_max_age => '60',
    }
exec {
  'chage':
   path => '/usr/bin/',
   command => 'chage -d 0 askar',
  }
}
```

The issue with the above manifests is that every time the agent pulls the manifests the password is again set to the default password and then the user is forced to change his password .

So, in order to avoid this I am adding the `refreshonly` parameter as follows

```
 exec {
   'chage':
    path => '/usr/bin/',
    command => 'chage -d 0 askar',
    subscribe => File['askar'],
    refreshonly => true,
   }
  }
```

I then verified that after applying the `refreshonly` parameter , the
   password is not getting changed to the default password and also `chage`
   in `exec` is not getting executed . But I had few doubts regarding how  refreshonly parameter works and I am not sure whether it is working fine for me.

1) Since `refreshonly` is an `exec` parameter  using it inside `exec` will not cause `chage -d 0 askar` to execute unless there is a change in `user` resource manifests. Am i correct here ? Does this also means that `user` resource will also not be executed along with `exec` because of the `refreshonly` parameter which means the user password  will not be set to default which was defined in `user` resource ?

2) I tried to change `password_min_age => '20' to password_min_age => '30',`  now since this is a change in `user` manifests , I am expecting that `exec` resource will get executed with `chage` command and user will be forced to change his password. But I am not seeing this change . Is my understanding wrong here ?

3) or the way I am defining `refreshonly` parameter itself is wrong. The syntax should have been  `subscribe => User['askar'],` instead of `subscribe => File['askar'],`

Answer (score 2):

@Zama Ques : Considering your problem i faced exactly the same issue which you asked in your point no: 3 that changing any attributes in the user resource , exec resource is not getting executed which it should according to our thought . But, the problem is you and I did the wrong thing in putting the "notify/subscribe" key in the exec resource. Think like this , if any attributes gets changed in the user resource then it should "notify" the exec resource to get executed. isn't it ? not the other way round. 
Look at my manifest below :

```
user { "john" :
        ensure => 'present',
        uid => '502',
        password => '$1$3uCLHGag$TVHLvE9T14XVSYoKA4YlH1' ,
        managehome => 'true',
        notify => EXEC['password change']
        }

exec { 'password change' :
        command => 'chage -d 0 john' ,
        path => '/usr/bin',
        refreshonly => 'true'

        }
```

~
~
When am changing password to `"$1$QmJsatk6$4B.7Ksj5D608SHb/qVscM0"` , then its notifying the exec resource to execute.

if we put "notify" in the exec resource , whatever you change in the user resource the exec resource will not execute . It all depends where you specify the "notify". Tips: The resource you expect to be changed , apply notify there itself. Hope this makes the concept clear.

To your 3rd question : look at my manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the `password` attribute to a `user` resource isn't required.  If you don't provide a password I believe puppet leaves it disabled, but you would need to test.  I know if you don't provide a password, then puppet doesn't change the password of an existing account.

I don't have an environment to test but I believe you could have your user resource that creates the account without a password, then have a notify that notifies an exec that does something like `usermod -p '$1$T7iMiuVY$bVjrtyWV4diXBKlCgcDKT0'` or something.

Comment: Will be great if you tell me the exact syntax of using refresh only. Can it only be used with file and exec resource as I am asking in point 3)

Comment: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#exec-attribute-refreshonly The command should only be run as a refresh mechanism for when a dependent object is changed.  **Changed** means the state of the system, was different then the state described in the manifests so puppet applied a change for an object.  So if the password for the user on the system is not exactly '$1$T7iMiuVY$bVjrtyWV4diXBKlCgcDKT0' during any puppet run then the user is changed to have that password, and that will trigger the exec refresh.

Comment: Basically if you define a password in the user object, then that password will not be changeable.  Messing around with the refreshonly on an exec  resource will not have any effect.